# Scrollable list of subpanels in labview

Tags: user-interface, labview

I am making a program that sweeps software parameters of a DUT and logs measurements from various instruments while doing so.

To make this program more flexible, I want the user to be able to configure an arbitrary set of instruments (including multiple of the same kind) to log measurements from. Each instrument has different configuration parameters.

What i need is a dynamic UI, where I can add (and remove) Instruments and have a different configuration UI for each instrument.
I made a little sketch of what I have in mind: [UI proposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Errqq.png)

What I tried so far is to have an Array of a Cluster with a Subpanel in it, but all the Subpanels in the Array show the same VI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a cluster or an array, the basic idea for making something like this work is to have one subpanel which will contain multiple subpanels inside it and populate/position/resize/show/hide them, etc.

See this thread for a discussion and a basic example I posted there - http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Independent-cursors-on-array-of-cluster-of-graphs-or-work-around/m-p/2319700#M728304

(Note - that thread shows a discussion and expansion on the topic. The original simpler example is here - http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/User-interface-problem-list-of-clusters/m-p/2311770#M726599 )

While I always liked the idea of this, I never actually needed it for an actual UI, so I don't think I have anything to add beyond this example. Also note that the example is very crude and only meant to demonstrate this concept.

Note that there are two ways of handling the number of panels - have enough to be displayed and control which VIs they show based on the scroll bar or create "enough" subpanels and control their visibility.

Comment: Thanks, that samples is exactly what I need. (Although it seems awfully complicated, but I guess this sort of UI is not really the strength of Labview)

Comment: I see I linked to the second thread. My example was in the thread I linked to there and is actually fairly simple (although, again, crude, so it's actually too simple). Maybe you only looked at the code in the thread I linked to. 


I don't think you can get much simpler than that in presenting an arbitrary list of VIs of different sizes as an array (although that example does need to be cleaned up to be usable). I'll add the link to the original example to the answer above.  

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/User-interface-problem-list-of-clusters/m-p/2311770#M726599

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of doing this is 2 subpanels. One stays on the main screen with your current vi running. When you want to switch vis load the new vi into the off screen subpanel. Move the positions of the subpanels so that the new one is on screen. Unload the old one and allow the new one to start. The old one is now ready for the next vi to run

Comment: This is my preferred solution for this challenge. It avoids the half-scrolled situation of the solution presented by Yair. But Yair's is better if you want the smooth scrolling. I just find I usually do not.

Comment: How is that different from simply having a single subpanel? No need to play with them at all if you only want to see one VI on the screen at each time.

If you still want to see more than one VI, but don't want the smooth scrolling, you could modify my example to consider the size of the container and use buttons or an external scrollbar to control the origin or how many VIs are shown. It would just require more code to manage.

Comment: Because I can then scroll the two subpanels in any direction to make a scrolling screen. I can also make sure that everything on the off-screen VI is ready to go and initialised before brining it on screen, giving a cleaner interface.